# Script editor web part is missing in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

In our SharePoint online site, we don't see the script editor web part from media and content section of webparts category. I have googled and found some relevant information like by default scripting will be disabled in SharePoint online... we need to enable it from SharePoint online admin center...as per the documentation,the changes may take 24 hours to get reflected - now it's been more than 24 hours but still we don't see the script editor web part from SharePoint online page. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks 
Rahul

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because web application administration is outside the scope of Stack Overflow as defined in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You may have better luck having this question migrated to SO's sister site [SharePoint Stack Exchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known behavior in SharePoint online - sometimes even though we enable the custom scripting, we will not be able to add the script editor web part. For that we need to run the below powershell code:

```
$adminUserID="youradminaccount@< sprnd.onmicrosoft.com >"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUserID -Message “Enter password”

Connect-SPOService -Url https://sprnd-admin.sharepoint.com/ -Credential $userCredential

Set-SPOsite "https://sprnd.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite001" -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Reference URL:
https://global-sharepoint.com/2019/08/24/how-to-enable-script-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint-online-site/

Comment: Thank you so much Global SharePoint Diary... I am able to add the script editor web part now using the above PowerShell code.